# Change scraped output

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a loop putting URLs into my broswer and scraping its content, generating this output:

2PRACE,0.0014

Hispanic,0.1556

API,0.0688

Black,0.0510

AIAN,0.0031

White,0.7200

The code looks like this:

```
f1 = open('urlz.txt','r',encoding="utf8")
ethnicity_urls = f1.readlines()
f1.close()

from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import openpyxl
import pprint

for each in ethnicity_urls:
    time.sleep(1)
    scraped = request.urlopen(each)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(scraped)
    soup1 = soup.select('p')
    print(soup1)
    resultFile = open('results.csv','a')
    resultFile.write(pprint.pformat(soup1))
    resultFile.close()
```

My problem is quite simple yet I do not find any tool that helps me achieve it. I would like to change the output from a list with "\n" in it to this:
2PRACE,0.0014 Hispanic,0.1556 API,0.0688 Black,0.0510 AIAN,0.0031 White,0.7200

I did not succeed by using replace as it told me I am treating a number of elements the same as a single element. 
My approach here was:

```
for each in ethnicity_urls:
    time.sleep(1)
    scraped = request.urlopen(each)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(scraped)
    soup1 = soup.select('p')
    soup2 = soup1.replace('\n',' ')
    print(soup2)
    resultFile = open('results.csv','a')
    resultFile.write(pprint.pformat(soup2))
    resultFile.close()
```

Can you help me find the correct approach to mutate the output before writing it to a csv?
The error message I get:
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'replace'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

---

See the solution to the problem in my answer below. Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? That error message seems rather clear to me, no? Have you one any debugging?

Comment: Yes I understood the error but formulating the solution didn't work out first as I thought it would. With the help from the other responses I could solve the issue, see my answer to the problem further down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the soup.

Soup is a list of elements:

The BS4 Documentation is excellent and has many many examples:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Use `strip()` to remove the `\n`

```
for x in soup1:    
    for r in x.children:
        try:
            print(r.strip())
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

soup1 seems to be an iterable, so you cannot just call replace on it.
Instead you could loop through all string items in soup1 and then call replace for every single one of them and then save the changes string to your soup2 variable. Something like this:

```
for e in soup1:
    soup2.append(e.replace('\n',' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for the ideas and resources. I think I could implement what you suggested. The current build is

```
for each in ethnicity_urls:
    time.sleep(1)
    scraped = request.urlopen(each)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(scraped)
    soup1 = soup.select('p')
    for e in soup1:
        soup2 = str(soup1)
        soup2 = soup2.replace('\n','')
        print(soup2)
    resultFile = open('results.csv','a')
    resultFile.write(pprint.pformat(soup2))
    resultFile.close()
```

And works just fine. I can do the final adjustments now in excel.